# GDB debugging x86 Assembler code on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, debugging, gcc, assembly, gdb

I've been trying to find an answer to this on stackoverflow for about an hour now, seems that a lot of similar problems are around but none really fitting to mine.

**Information about what tools I'm using can be found further down!**

I am writing my own compiler for a subset of the java language and thus creating assembler code. Now I'm at a point where I need to debug said assembler code to locate a bug. The problem is when I compile my assembler code to a binary with `gcc -m32 -g myAssembler.s` I get the following warning:

```
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch i386)
```

(This warning also occurs using `-ggdb, -ggdb2,  -ggdb3, -g2, -g3`instead of `-g`

Since there are no debug symbols I can't use `gdb` to debug my code. I don't know much about linking and how it's done or who does it (especially on a Mac), so precise/noob-friendly answers would be very welcome.

---

---

## Tools I'm using:

**The assembly created from my compiler is x86, 32-bit GAS Syntax**.

I am using **OS X Mavericks** with **GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6** downloaded via **MacPorts** (They changed its name to `ggdb`. The `ggdb --version` command shows also a line saying :

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0".
```

(Not quite sure if that's important.)

Running `gcc --version` returns:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: This is probably connected with Apple dropping support for GDB in Xcode 5 and you are using the version of gcc that comes with Xcode 5. You probably need to change compiler or debugger (to lldb).

Comment: @CRD Judging from the fact that GDB seems to work just fine what other compiler than gcc would you recommend?

Comment: I can't recommend any, haven't tried what you are doing, but you might look at llvm-gcc (which Xcode 5 also drops support for). Try www.llvm.org for a download. But that might be more trouble than using lldb (if your problem is indeed connected to Xcode 5's changes). Good luck!

Comment: @CRD Thank you very much, I just downloaded gcc-4.2 from homebrew and that seems to work for lldb (which is still supported by Xcode 5 it seems). If you want you can put an answer to this question and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably connected with Apple dropping support for GDB in Xcode 5 and you are using the version of gcc that comes with Xcode 5. You probably need to change compiler or debugger (to lldb)… you might look at llvm-gcc (which Xcode 5 also drops support for). Try www.llvm.org for a download. But that might be more trouble than using lldb (if your problem is indeed connected to Xcode 5's changes). Good luck! – CRD

I just downloaded gcc-4.2 from homebrew and that seems to work for lldb (which is still supported by Xcode 5 it seems). – Octoshape